# How do I create a new instance of a Schema and save it to the database?

Tags: javascript, express, mongoose, user-registration

I have a UserSchema that just has two strings: username and password.

I am trying to add a new user to the database through a HTML form.

I have a route: '/signup'

This is what I have:

```js
app.post('/signup', function(req, res){
  // Hash the password
  var salt = bcrypt.genSaltSync(10);
  var hash = bcrypt.hashSync(req.body.password, salt);

  User.create({username: req.body.username, password: hash}, function (err, user) {
    console.log("signing up...");
     if (err){
       console.log("something went wrong");
       return res.redirect('/signup');
     }
     saved!
  });
});
```

I have been following a mix of different tutorials and videos. From debugging I know the salt/hashing is fine. It's the create causing the problem. When I submit the HTML form, it just hangs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just realised that I am not redirecting anywhere when it is successful. Added in a redirect and it works now.